# Informix JDBC PreparedStatement UPDATE Multiset

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, informix

I want to change MULTISET column of the table, and my code looks something like this:

```
PreparedStatement pstm = preparedStatement("UPDATE table SET mc = MULTISET{?, ?} WHERE ...");
pstm.setString(1, "...");
pstm.setString(2, "...");
pstm.execute();
```

And I get error: **"Illegal attempt to convert a collection type into another type."**.

What is wrong with this? When I put real values instead of '?' everything works just fine.

Btw... *mc* is defined like *MULTISET(CHAR(20) NOT NULL)*

Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

I tested it using JDBC Informix drivers 3.50 and Jython 2.5.1 and it works. Maybe you use some old version of JDBC? I tested it both with `execute()` and `executeUpdate()` method. My code:

```
from java.sql import DriverManager
from java.lang import Class

Class.forName("com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver")

db = DriverManager.getConnection(db_url, usr, passwd)
pstm = db.prepareStatement("UPDATE aaa_mc_test SET mc_test = MULTISET{?, ?}")
pstm.setString(1, "...")
pstm.setString(2, "...")
r = pstm.executeUpdate()
print('ok, updated: %d' % (r))
```

For 3 records I inserted to `aaa_mc_test` table it prints out `ok, updated: 3`